# Can Cmake add 'time' before ./main in the command line to measure program execution time?

Tags: c++, time, cmake, clion

I am wanting to measure the time it takes for my C++ video processing program to process a video. I am using CLion to write the program and have Cmake set up to compile and automatically run the program with a test video. However, in order to find execution time I have been using the following command in the MacOS terminal:

`% time ./main ../Media/test_video.mp4`

Is there a way for me to configure Cmake to automatically include `time` in the execution of `./main` to streamline my process further?

So far I've tried using `set(CMAKE_ARGS time "test_video.mp4")` and some command line argument functions but they don't seem to be acting in the way that I'm looking for.

Comment: CMake is used to compile a program. Running it is done by CLion itself, you have settings in Run configurations. I'm not exactly sure how to do that best, probably a shell script configuration that will call `time` and your executable? Although that's missing an option to build a target before launch, you would probably have to include that in your script as well.

Comment: Dang that totally didn't click for me, thanks for spelling it out haha. I'll look into CLion run configs further then. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) or [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) could be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use `add_custom_target` to do what you want. I'll not consider this option further as it seems abusing the build system for something it wasn't designed to do. Yet it may have an advantage over using CLion configuration: it would be available to be used outside of CLion. That advantage seems minor: why not run the desired command directly in those contexts?

The first CLion method would be to define an external tool which run time on the current build target. In File|Settings...|Tools|External Tools define a new tool with `/bin/time` as program, `$CMakeCurrentProductFile$ $Prompt$` as arguments. When choosing that tools (in Tools|External Tools) it will now prompt you for the argument and then run `/bin/time` on the current target with the provided arguments. Advantage: you don't have to define the tool once, it will be available in every project. Inconvenients: the external tools are available in every project, thus it doesn't make sense to be more specific than `$Prompt$` for the arguments and the working directory; it isn't possible to specify environment variables, it isn't possible to enforce the need of a build before running the command.

The second CLion method would to be define a Run/Debug Configuration. Again use `/bin/time` as program (chose "Custom Executable"), specify `$CMakeCurrentProductFile$` as first  argument (here it makes sense to provide the other arguments as desired, but note that `$Prompt$` is still a valid choice if needed). Advantages: it makes sense to be as specific as needed; you have all the feature of configurations (environment variables, input redirections, specifying actions to be executed before the execution). Inconvenient: it doesn't work with other CLion features which assume that the program is the target such as the debugger, the profiler, ... so you may have to duplicate configurations to get them.

Note that the methods aren't exclusive: you can define an external tools and then add configurations for the case where it is more convenient.

Comment: Awesome, I decided to use the second given CLion method. Thanks a ton for the help!